# codeigniter- object not found -base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, base-url

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24

**config:**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/1/';
```

**autoload**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'html');
```

site_url works for me but when I used base_url it doesn't work.
I prefer to use base_url() than site_url.

How to run my code?

Comment: where and how exactly you use site_url/base_url, and which are you using - the variable or the function? I don't see any code that is problematic in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your config, 
You can replace

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/1/';
```

With

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost';
```

Or

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Yoursite';
```

Hope this working